# I cant assign a value to an javascript object key

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

im trying to make a tetris game , and ive made some progress, but im stuck with an object key assignement problem,
what im trying to do now is detect collisions of the shapes and what i thought of is to keep track of each shape's position
,by storing the coordinates in an object called `alreadyOccupiedPos`
and this objects stores the shapes as keys
,for example the key name of the first shape to appear will be '1' and the key name of the second shape to appear is '2' ect...
and each shape has a value as an array of arrays, the array includes the squares that make up the shape and each square
is represented as a sub-array, and the sub-array has two elements, the current row and the current column where
the square is within the board. I started by giving the `alreadyOccupiedPos object`  a default key for the first shape.
And i have two key variables , the first one is `numberOfSquares` which represents the number of squares that the shape consists of,
and it gets reseted each time a new shape gets created or moved and then the i have `shapeNumber` which is a default parameter in the function that i can use to to refer
to the shape number in the alreadyOccupiedPos object .Now to the problem im facing , in the second loop where the shape drawing happens , and along with drawing the shape,
im trying to insert the location of each square in the `alreadyOccupiedPos object`  by pushing an array that includes the current row and the current column where the
square is into the array that includes the squares of the shape, and this is what i tried to do `alreadyOccupiedPos[shapeNumber][numberOfSquares] = [j + step, i + randomHorizantalPos];`
and the problem is it just doesnt get assigned.
this is the codepen :
https://codepen.io/marwanoss/pen/gOmxPoP?editors=0010
this is the js code:

```
let tableBody = document.querySelector('table').children[0];
let tableRows = Array.from(tableBody.children)

//shapes
let L_shape = [
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1]
];

let S_shape = [
    [0, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0]
];

let Z_shape = [
    [1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1]
];

let J_shape = [
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1]
];

let square_shape = [
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1]
];

let I_shape = [
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0]
];

let T_shape = [
    [1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0]
]

let shapes = [L_shape, S_shape, Z_shape, J_shape, square_shape, I_shape, T_shape]

    , colors = ['red', 'black', 'green', 'yellow', 'cyan', 'rgb(44, 10, 10)']

    , randomlyChosenColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]

    , randomlyChosenShape = shapes[Math.floor(Math.random() * shapes.length)]

    , randomHorizantalPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13)

    , numberOfSquares = 0

    , clearLimit = tableRows.length

    , alreadyOccupiedPos = { 1: [] };

function recur(step = 0, shapeNumber = 1) {
    //this condition checks whether a shape has reached the bottom of the board or not, if so a new shape gets generated and the position get reseted to the top of the board.
    if (step === 17) {
        clearLimit = step;

        randomHorizantalPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);

        randomlyChosenShape = shapes[Math.floor(Math.random() * shapes.length)];

        randomlyChosenColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

        alreadyOccupiedPos[shapeNumber + 1] = [];

        numberOfSquares = 0;

        recur(0, shapeNumber)

    } else {

        //this for loop clears the board
        for (let i = 0; i < tableRows.slice(0, clearLimit - 1).length; i++) {
            for (let j = randomHorizantalPos; j < randomHorizantalPos + 3; j++) {
                tableRows[i].children[j].style.backgroundColor = 'white'
            }
        }

        //after the board gets cleared by the previous loop this loop creates the shape by giving the squares a background color to create the illusion of the shape moving by adding a step in each recursive call
        for (let i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < randomlyChosenShape.length; j++) {
                if (randomlyChosenShape[j][i] === 1) {
                    tableRows[j + step].children[i + randomHorizantalPos].style.backgroundColor = randomlyChosenColor;
                    alreadyOccupiedPos[shapeNumber][numberOfSquares] = [j + step, i + randomHorizantalPos];
                    numberOfSquares++;
                }
            }
        }

        setTimeout(() => {
            numberOfSquares = 0;
            recur(step + 1, shapeNumber)
        }, 1000);

    }

}

recur()
```

and this is the html (thats alot of html lol, i could've created the html using a loop in js i just forgot xD) :

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="tetris.js"></script>
</body>
```

and this is the css:

```
body{
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: black;
}

html{
    font-size: 10px;
}

table{
    background-color: white;
    height: 60rem;
    width: 50rem;
    margin: 5% auto;
}

table td{
    background-color: white;
    border: black .1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked, that the condition (`randomlyChosenShape[j][i] === 1`) really passes?

Comment: @Teemu yep it defenetly does, otherwise the shape wouldnt get drawn, you understand why the condition is there right?

Answer (score 0):

`alreadyOccupiedPos[shapeNumber][numberOfSquares]` has already been assigned. Maybe you need to change the line

```js
recur(0, shapeNumber)
```

to

```js
recur(0, shapeNumber + 1);
```

to assign the value to the newly created array.